# Why are files named .part when they are being downloaded by applications?

Tags: file, download

For example, firefox - when it downloads a file, it downloads it to `myfile.jpg.part` instead of `myfile.jpg` I am just curious to why it does this.

Comment: Many reasons I can think of: So the OS doesn't try to generate thumbnails for image/video/other files, so that you don't try to run incomplete files with their default associations, so that you know the file is not complete yet and/or when it _is_ complete. Other reasons I'm sure. Maybe someone else can give an official reason.

Comment: I don't believe that is really a programming question, but I will give an answer...It's named with .part since it is in the process of getting downloaded. Once it's downloaded the .part is removed. Part = Partial (as in partial download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a partial file and it's used to prevent the user from opening incomplete files because that might result in unexpected behavior. also, they contain some meta data that allows the browser to pause and resume downloads.

Answer (score 0):

.PART is short for partially downloaded file. The extension is appended to incomplete files so that programs won't try to open them and crash/freeze due to the file not being complete. Once the download is complete, the extra extension is removed and you're good to go.